# The first key is not being recorded by keypress event

Tags: javascript

The keypress and keydown events are not recording the first keypress/down character, while the keyup event is working fine, I need in my case to use keypress but it's not recording the first char

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
  const input = document.querySelector('.input');

  input.addEventListener('keypress', (e)=>{
    demo.innerHTML = input.value;
  });
```

```html
<h1 class="demo"></h1>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write something">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Document: keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event)

> **Deprecated**
>
> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

Use [HTMLElement: input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) instead:

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
  demo.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<h1 class="demo"></h1>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write something">
```

If you want to detect which key is pressed then use [Document: keyup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event):

> The `keyup` event is fired when a key is released.

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.code);
  demo.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<h1 class="demo"></h1>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write something">
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that new developers often forget about copy-paste (say with the mouse) that will never trigger a key event, whilst the input event will cover every scenario.

Comment: How I can detect if the enter key was pressed by the input event?

Comment: @KyleTech, in that case you should use the `keyup` event, please check the updated answer:)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `keypress` event is fired before the field changes its value, while the `keyup` event is fired after

So when you detect the first keypress, the value of the input is still empty when you update the `demo` element

Answer (score 0):

This is due entirely to the behaviour of `keypress` itself.

`keypress` fires before the content of your `input` has been updated, so when you retrieve the value of the `input` it is still empty.

Instead, you can use the `keyup` event which will fire faithfully as you are expecting:

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
  demo.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<h1 class="demo"></h1>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write something">
```

Alternatively, you can use your knowledge that `keypress` fires before the `input` is updated, and simulate the new value of the `input` by appending `e.key` to it:

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('keypress', (e)=>{
  demo.innerHTML = input.value + e.key;
});
```

```html
<h1 class="demo"></h1>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="write something">
```